# loose values while converting list to dict in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Slack client rtm_read is giving JSON, but see it as list
This is my code

```
sc.rtm_connect()
while True:
    print(sc.rtm_read())
    time.sleep(1)
```

I got

```
{'presence': 'active', 'user': 'U7567QP0B', 'type': 'presence_change'}
```

I try to convert this way

```
for result in sc.rtm_read():
   d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(result)] * 2))
```

but loose value.

```
{'presence': 'user', 'type': None}
```

I need to get user value, like U7567QP0B in this example

Comment: You are creating a new `dict` object `d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(result)] * 2))` in each `for` loop iteration, instead you need to define a single `dict` object outside the for loop and update it inside the loop.

Comment: I don't get it, what are you trying to do with this complex dict you are creating ? If you wan the value from the key `'user'`, just use `sc.rtm_read().get('user')`